# PostgreSQL MIN and MAX function doesn't return one result

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSql DB, I have a table called `Trip`.

There is a column called `id` and a column called `meta` in the table.

An example of `id` in one row looks like:

```
id = 123456
```

An example of `meta` in one row looks like:

```
meta = {"runTime": 3922000, "distance": 85132, "duration": 4049000, "fuelUsed": 19.595927498516176}
```

I want to select the trip which has the minimum kph from the `Trip` table and show trip id and minimum kph. This is my query:

```
select tp."id" tripid, MIN((3600 * (tp."meta"->>'distance')::numeric)
   / ((tp."meta"->>'runTime')::NUMERIC)) minkph FROM "Trip" tp 
WHERE tp."createdAt" BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00+00'
                      and '2020-04-30 00:00:00+00'
GROUP BY tp."id"
```

However this query returns all trip ids and division calculation results, not only one row.

Could you please help?

Comment: Sorry, I edited your question. I don't like horizonatel scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order by` the calculated `kph` field and return only the first:

```
select tp."id" tripid, MIN((3600 * (tp."meta"->>'distance')::numeric)
   / ((tp."meta"->>'runTime')::NUMERIC)) minkph FROM "Trip" tp 
WHERE tp."createdAt" BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00+00'
                      and '2020-04-30 00:00:00+00'
GROUP BY tp."id"
order by 2
limit 1
```

Comment: If the `id` is unique, the GROUP BY clause is harmless, but useless there. Just remove it and remove also the MIN function.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1 - General min by id:**

You're expressing the column `tp.id` on your query so, your select will run the `MIN()` for every group of `id`. If you want the global `MIN()` for your query, just make this:

```
SELECT MIN((3600 * (tp."meta"->>'distance')::numeric) / ((tp."meta"->>'runTime')::NUMERIC)) minkph 
  FROM "Trip" tp 
 WHERE tp."createdAt" BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00+00' 
   AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00+00'
```

Every group function groups by a set of distinct data, if you don't pass any column except the `MIN()`, the query will result the global result in one line, for all rows.

**Approach 2 - General min:**

If you want to get the `MIN()` and the respective `id`, you can do as follows and do a `LIMIT 1`. as is:

```sql
    SELECT tp."id" AS tripid, ((3600 * (tp."meta"->>'distance')::numeric) / ((tp."meta"->>'runTime')::NUMERIC)) minkph 
      FROM "Trip" tp 
     WHERE tp."createdAt" BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00+00' 
       AND '2020-04-30 00:00:00+00'
     ORDER BY 2
     LIMIT 1
```

In time. You can use window functions, but is a bit complex to do.

Comment: Thanks, I want to see tp.id too. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to get the `MIN()` value for every trip? or list the `MIN()` value for a set of trips and list all `ids` in which that you have selected in your time window?

Comment: I want to select the trip which has MIN() value and only show this trip's id and MIN()value

Comment: Ok, added a approach for your needs;